# Docker compose PHP container needs to hit nginx proxy with Host header. How?

Tags: docker, nginx, proxy, fastcgi, guzzle

I have 3 containers. A container that is an nginx reverse proxy:

```
nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy:latest
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    networks:
      - network
```

Behind that are two php fpm containers on that network. Container A and container B with hostname A and B respectively. I also added these to my local hostsfile:

```
127.0.0.1 A
127.0.0.1 B
```

So I can reach from them from my localhost. Both respond to fastCGI requests.

Now I need to do a Guzzle request in A to go to B. This should go via the nginx proxy. How do I add an entry to container A's hostsfile so a request to B will go to `nginx-proxy` with the header `Host: B`. But adding

```
extra_hosts:
    - "B:nginx-proxy"
```

Won't work and I can't find any other way other than hardcoding it which I do not want to do for obvious reasons.

Docker compose file:

```
  containerA:
    build:
      context: 'docker'
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
      - ./docker/www.conf:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/zz-docker.conf
    networks:
      - network
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: containerA
      VIRTUAL_ROOT: /var/www/html/public/index.php
      VIRTUAL_PROTO: fastcgi

  containerB:
    build:
      context: 'docker'
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
      - ./docker/www.conf:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/zz-docker.conf
    networks:
      - network
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: containerB
      VIRTUAL_ROOT: /var/www/html/public/index.php
      VIRTUAL_PROTO: fastcgi

  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy:latest
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
    networks:
      - network
    environment:
      DEFAULT_HOST: containerA

networks:
  network:
    driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 0):

In the docker-compose file you are ready placed the environment variables - "VIRTUAL_HOST" in the container A and B?

```
services:
  proxy:
    ........
    ........
  containerA:
    ........
    envirinment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST=A

  containerB:
    ........
    envirinment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST=B
```

If you tried this, maybe the complete docker-file will help us.
cheers

Comment: Yes I did this. But containerA cannot directly contact containerB since it only responds to fastcgi requests from the nginx proxy. So the route should be `containerA -> nginx-proxy with header Host: containerB -> containerB`